# T-SQL bulk insert fails on specific word "DENY" in string-data

Tags: sql-server, bulk-insert

I have CSV files structured as string **;** string **;** string
First string is quoted with "". The other 2 strings are not.
I'm bulk inserting them into a table using nchar(x) for each of the 3 columns with a sufficiently large value for x.

```
BULK INSERT [table] FROM 'import.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ';')
```

This has been working for a couple of years.
Since a few days the import is giving issues on some rows. After investigation each of the failing rows gets a conversion/type mismatch error on the 3rd column.
The thing that has changed about the data is that in the middle of this 3rd string the text **(DENY)** is now present in each of the failing rows. This was previously never the case.

```
 Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
 Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for row 1019, column 3 (Rights).
```

Any ideas why the presence of the substring (DENY) causes this to happen ?
(I know it is a SQL reserved word, but why is it parsed in this position ?)
How to work around it ? I still need those rows to be imported, including that text.

Sample content of column 3:

```
(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
(I)(OI)(CI)(DENY)(WDAC,WO,S,DC)
(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
```

The 2nd line gives the error. The other 2 import fine.
(And in case you are wondering: Yes, it is ICACLS output that I am parsing.)

Comment: Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: @JohnM Added the exact error message. The error refers to the line with the data-sample I gave further down.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the deny word that is causing the problem. I just did a quick test and was able to bulk insert a file with your example data without issue. Is it possible that that are some hidden/special characters in those rows as well. you can use something like notepad++ to open the file and view hidden/special characters.

Comment: @BobKlimes Nothing hidden. Already checked the files with Notepad++. And the files are generated by a script I wrote myself. I can vouch for there not being any weird hidden characters. I have about 300 sample lines in 12 files that cause the error. They ALL have that (DENY) part. If I remove the word DENY form those lines (or just remove 1 character of the word) they import fine. I can do that as a final cleanup step in my own script, but I like to avoid that if possible, because I would like to keep all the post-processing in 1 place (SQL).

Comment: Can you show the whole line? Above you say your string is separated with `;` but I see no such characters. Also, what are the data types of the table? I agree with Bob that `DENY` is a red herring - it's not causing this issue.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Will provide some exact sample-lines tomorrow. I'm at home now and can't access that server from here. For this moment: General structure is: "unc path";domain\adgroupname;(I)(OI)(CI)(DENY)(WDAC,WO,S,DC) followed by 2 spaces and CRLF. unc path and adgroupname may contain spaces too. As I said in the question: Columns are nchar(200), nchar(100) and nchar(100). (I'm certain no input is ever longer than that.) By the way: It's SQL2005. Still waiting for the SQL2014 server to be delivered.

Comment: Why does your BULK INSERT not have a ROWTERMINATOR? I suspect CRLF is messing you up there.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Because CRLF is the default anyway? (MSDN says \n, but the CR is implicitly added. If you really need just a linefeed, like a Unix file, you must specify '0x0a' as terminator.) I checked and the offending lines have CRLF like all the other lines. I will create a sample tomorrow that (for me) produces the error and post that tomorrow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks a clear reproduction script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I found the following:

The word `DENY` is indeed a red herring. The problem is caused by the `(xx,xx,xx,xx)` sequence behind it.
For some obscure reason this causes errors if the bulk insert is run from a dynamic SQL string.
(I was using dynamic SQL as I need to iterate through a list of input filenames derived from another table. bulk insert doesn't allow the use of a variable for the input filename. So I had to programmatically generate each bulk insert statement and then `EXEC()` it.)

The bulk insert with the same input file works fine if run directly. BCP import of the same file is OK too.

If the column containing this sequence is NOT the last column of the input row, it works as expected.

As I have full control of the script that generates these files I could add a 4th dummy column containing just a `=`. This solved the issues with the bulk insert.

Obviously I still don't understand the root-cause of this. At least I have a workaround.

Microsoft states on MSDN numerous times that

> "bulk insert of CSV files is not supported, but may work in some
>   cases"

They NEVER say why or what the exact problem is...
Makes me wonder if I have run into a known problem...